# Interaction terms in multinomial logit regression

Tags: interaction, multinomial-distribution

I'm analyzing the relationship between women's BMI status (underweight, normal, overweight) and five predictors ( their wealth, their education, the region where they live, their score of dietary diversity and a variable indicating if they treat the water they drink using a good method). For interpretation purposes, I chose to use a multinomial logit model rather than an ordinal logit regression. My reference category for the outcome is the 'Normal BMI" and this variable is coded : 1=Underweight, 2=Normal, 3=Overweight.

Investigating potential interactions between my independent variables, I found an interaction between the region (3 levels) and the treatment of water (3 levels : No treatment, Treatment but not with an improved method and Improved method). However, this interaction is significant only for the Overweight vs normal equation :

**The model specification I used in Stata** 
 
qui mlogit bmi_group_int i.region##i.treat

**Testing the significiance of the interaction for underweight vs normal** 
 
. testparm i.treat#i.region, equation(#1)

( 1)  [1]2.region#1.treat = 0   
 
( 2)  [1]2.region#2.treat = 0  
( 3)  [1]3.region#1.treat = 0  
( 4)  [1]3.region#2.treat = 0

```
 chi2(  4) =    3.80 
 Prob > chi2 =    0.4342
```

**Testing the significiance of the interaction for overweight vs normal**

(    1)  [3]2.region#1.treat = 0 
   (    2)  [3]2.region#2.treat = 0 
   (    3)  [3]3.region#1.treat = 0 
   (    4)  [3]3.region#2.treat = 0

```
    chi2(  4) =    9.89
    Prob > chi2 =    0.0424
```

Then, if I compare the model with interaction and the model without interaction, the likelihood ratio test tells that the model with interaction doesn't fit significantly better than the model without interaction (p= 0.087).Also, the model with interaction as a bigger AIC and BIC.

Should I drop the interaction term ? I'm afraid to loose informations if I did that.

Comment: You should probably not drop it, but first, have a look at the fitted probabilities in both models. Then it will be easier to judge if the difference is important! Have a look at  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246873/ols-vs-logistic-regression-does-the-interpretation-of-interaction-differs/247035#247035

Comment: Thank you very much ! However, I'm wondering how to present my result, as I have an interaction only for one of the two equations and this latter is estimated for both..

Comment: You should probably inclide the interaction for both equations (or exclude from both).